# How do I determine what ip range a device is using?

Tags: python, networking

This is kind of a weird problem, basically I have a computer connected to a machine via ethernet cable. There is no other network or internet access. The machine sets up a network which allows you to telnet into it.

I need the simplest way possible to determine the ip range the device is using. This would be turned into a python script. It is not just the obvious 192.168.x.x

I'm looking at the 'arp' command, but also a library called 'netifaces'. I'm not sure if there's something simpler I could use. It has to work for Linux, OSX and Windows. The machine is running an android OS

Basically, I just need to be able to determine what ip ranges the device is currently using in the simplest possible way.

The command 'arp -a' seems to be the most promising right now.

Comment: In other words you try to find the machine's ip ??

Comment: What type of machine is it?  Do you have any documentation on it's setup?  You say it "sets up a network", could it possibly be acting as a DHCP server too?  You can try using a packet analyzer, like Wireshark, to see if you can find it there.

Comment: @coder Yes I am, and I can do that with nmap, but I don't know the ip range to scan. Nmap works very well for this, I just cannot figure out how to find the range to scan like 'nmap x.x.*.0/24'

Comment: @pferate wireshark works nicely but this needs to be automated, I am more or less looking for some type of command universal across machines that could give some information about networks currently connected to, I am doing this now by extracting network interface information and filtering out subnet masks etc

I believe it's setting up a DHCP server, and it's an android OS.

Comment: I think you need to forget some assumptions. You statement, "_...the obvious 192.168.x.x_" shows a bias toward residential networking. There is really nothing obvious about that network range. Also, do not assume a network is `/24`. A network mask length can be just about any length between `/8` and `/31`, inclusive.

Comment: I am saying that it DOES NOT work on 192.168.x.x, i.e. that will never be the range.

I am using nmap to scan and /24 is scanning x.x.*.0-255

Comment: @user5275692,  you don't know the interface, you don't know the subnet, so you are not only looking for ip as you said before ...

Comment: @coder

Right now I am running something to extract interface information, I'm filtering out all subnet masks and dud ips, then I'm nmap scanning over the range of those ips for specific ports. There is no other external network, it is only what exists between the computer and machine. Internet access is in fact turned off. The goal is to find the ip, but this can be achieved by finding the relevant ip range because in that range, only a single machine running on specific ports should be found.

Comment: Why would assume that the network is `/24`? On a point-to-point link, which is what it sounds like you have, the mask length could be `/30` or `/31`. You need to quit making assumptions, and just look at what is assigned to the interface.

Comment: Also, if this is not assigned by DHCP, you are probably using the Link-Local address range (`169.254.0.0/16`). That is a `/16` address range, not a `/24` address range. Addresses are randomly assigned anywhere in that `/16` range.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks so much!! I was not aware 169.254.x.x was fixed! That's the range I keep seeing again and again!! Wow that really helps, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Put that as answer and I will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IPv4 Link-Local range of `169.254.0.0/16` is used by APIPA for hosts to assign IP addresses when an interface has no other way to obtain an address. There are some rules about this range, e.g. you cannot subnet the range, it can't be routed, etc. See [RFC 3927, Dynamic Configuration of IPv4 Link-Local Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) for more information.

You really need to determine if the equipment on the other end of your link is using this range. If it is a specialized device, it probably does not, and it will have a fixed address which was manually assigned. If this is the case, you will not be able contact it with your Link-Local address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

get_ip_address('eth0')  # '192.168.0.110'
```

Comment: This will not work because network interfaces do not always name it 'eth0', for example ethernet interface on my machine right now is named:

'{HB232-123FH-J23JH}'

I made that up but this is the format.

Comment: you could just set it to x and get rid of eth0 and make it a variable this is a start you could do some work.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I am actually using that library right now, I have a proof of concept working, I am just not very happy with that solution, but it is working for now.